# Rotating and translating a polygon

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sf

I've come across a problem when I was trying to apply rotations and translations to a rectangle and then visualize both on `leaflet`. I am trying to rotate my rectangle 180° and then translate it downwards.

The problem is that after this transformation the new rectangle seems distorted (bigger along the y axis) although it should be the same size.

Here I've reproduced my code along with a photo of the result. I would appreciate any insight.

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

rect <- rbind(c(-1, -5), c(1, -5), c(1, 5), c(-1, 5), c(-1, -5))
rect_poly<- st_polygon(list(rect))

angle <- pi
rotation_matrix <- matrix(c(cos(angle), sin(angle), -sin(angle), cos(angle)), 2, 2)
rect_rot<- st_polygon(list(rect))*rotation_matrix  + c(0, -50)

leaflet() %>%
  addPolygons(data = rect_poly) %>%
  addPolygons(data = rect_rot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the [projection system](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/projections.html) `leaflet` uses.
If you use a simple cartesian `CRS`, there's no distorsion:

```
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(crs = leafletCRS(crsClass = "L.CRS.Simple"))) %>%
  addPolygons(data = rect_poly) %>%
  addPolygons(data = rect_rot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed "look" elongated. But this does not have anything to do with your rotation. For example if you place them right next to each other they are the same length:

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

rect <- rbind(c(-1, -5), c(1, -5), c(1, 5), c(-1, 5), c(-1, -5))
rect_poly<- st_polygon(list(rect))

angle <- pi
rotation_matrix <- matrix(c(cos(angle), sin(angle), -sin(angle), cos(angle)), 2, 2)
rect_rot<- st_polygon(list(rect %*% rotation_matrix)) + c(4, 0)

leaflet() %>%
  addPolygons(data = rect_poly) %>%
  addPolygons(data = rect_rot)
```

[image]

Maybe this is something with leaflet problem which goes beyond my experienced.

Note:
Rotations should be matrix multiplied, not element multiplied.